# Sound does not work on X-server, works in TTY, Arch Linux w/ALSA

Tags: linux, audio, xorg, arch-linux, alsa

My sound system isn't working when I use the X server. When I use it in a TTY, it works fine.

In a TTY, the output of aplay -l:

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 0: ALC889A Analog [ALC889A Analog]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 1: ALC889A Digital [ALC889A Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

In a graphical environment, this is the output:

```
aplay: device_list:268: no soundcards found...
```

Even stranger, the sound from the X environment starts playing when I do a VT switch, but doesn't play while I am in X.

Contents of /proc/asound/cards

```
 0 [Intel          ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel
                      HDA Intel at 0xfdff4000 irq 43
 1 [CX180          ]: CX23418 - CX18-0
                      CX23418 #0 Hauppauge HVR-1600 TV/FM Radio/Line-In Capture
```

I'm new at this, so if anything else is required, please let me know. Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue, in case anyone else was having this problem.

KDE (or whatever you use) must be run via systemd, so (in arch) run (as root) `systemctl enable kdm` and then it should work.